# HTML/JavaScript - How to get dropdown values into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have the following HTML table (datatable jquery plugin):

[image]

Every row of the table has a `input type = "hidden" name = WorkOrderID[]` with an ID number.

I wish to submit the value of the dropdowns marked with blue a green colors in the image in array form such as this:

```
array(         
        0=>    
            [WorkOrderID] : 10    
            [BlueDropdown] : 14    
            [GreenDropdown] : 22,
        1=> 
            [WorkOrderID] : 11    
            [BlueDropdown] : 45    
            [GreenDropdown] : 7,
        2=> 
            [WorkOrderID] : 12    
            [BlueDropdown] : null (in case no value was selected)    
            [GreenDropdown] : 69,
       )
```

I'm **NOT** a front end developer, so my knowledge of HTML and JS are basically null.
Can you please lend a hand? I need to get it done using JQuery

**EDIT:**
This is my "code" so far (sorry for it being an image, working remotely and can't copy/paste):
[image]

Comment: _“I'm NOT a front end developer, so my knowledge of HTML and JS are basically null”_ – time to hire someone then.

Comment: @CBroe aren't you helpful :)

Comment: This is a site for developers. If you want to get help here, then you need to come equipped with the necessary base knowledge in the techniques involved (otherwise, this is not question fit for this site, but a job offer, and those belong elsewhere.) If you want our help, then you need to show the relevant code that makes the problem reproducible (and not just as an image, it belongs directly into your question), and ask a specific enough question. Please go read [ask], and edit your question in those regards.

Comment: It would be better to post your code as text rather than an image so anyone trying to tweak it to get it to work doesn't have to retype the whole thing to answer your question. Just paste it into the question, highlight it and then press the `{}` button to indent it by 4 spaces so the SO knows to format it as code. Another reason to use text is that over the years links to images can break and anyone viewing your question in the future might not be able to get the full context of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following code. This may be something you are looking for. Check the console for output. Inspect Element > Console

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
table{
    margin:20px auto;
}
table td{
padding:10px;
    width:300px;
    background:#ededed;
}

button{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
p{
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table" valign="center">
<tr id="r1">
    <td class="select0">1</td>
    <td>
        <select class="select1">
            <option value="">First Select </option>
            <option value="value1">Option1 </option>
            <option value="value2">Option2 </option>
            <option value="value3">Option3 </option>
            <option value="value4">Option4 </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select class="select2">
            <option value="">Second Select </option>
            <option value="value1">Option1 </option>
            <option value="value2">Option2 </option>
            <option value="value3">Option3 </option>
            <option value="value4">Option4 </option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="row">
    <td class="select0">2</td>
    <td>
        <select class="select1">
            <option value="">First Select </option>
            <option value="value1">Option1 </option>
            <option value="value2">Option2 </option>
            <option value="value3">Option3 </option>
            <option value="value4">Option4 </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select class="select2">
            <option value="0">Second Select </option>
            <option value="value1">Option1 </option>
            <option value="value2">Option2 </option>
            <option value="value3">Option3 </option>
            <option value="value4">Option4 </option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="row">
    <td class="select0">3</td>
    <td>
        <select class="select1">
            <option value="0">First Select </option>
            <option value="value1">Option1 </option>
            <option value="value2">Option2 </option>
            <option value="value3">Option3 </option>
            <option value="value4">Option4 </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select class="select2">
            <option value="0">Second Select </option>
            <option value="value1">Option1 </option>
            <option value="value2">Option2 </option>
            <option value="value3">Option3 </option>
            <option value="value4">Option4 </option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>
<br>
<button class="button-click">Click Here</button>
<p id="output"></p>
<script>

$(".button-click").on("click",(function(){
    var arr = [];
    $("#table tr").each(function() {
    let temp = {};
        temp.WorkOrderID = $(this).find(".select0").html();
        temp.BlueDropdown = $(this).find(".select1").val();
        temp.GreenDropdown = $(this).find(".select2").val();
        arr.push(temp);
    });
    console.log(arr);
}));

</script>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using `temp` as an object, instead of declaring it as an array, you should declare it as an object `var temp = {};`. Also, it should be declared with `var`, `let` or `const` or it will be an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), which is a very bad thing. Also, you don't need the `type="text/javascript"` on the `script` tag. All browsers that support the `script` tag default to JS, you're just wasting bytes using it.

Comment: @UselessCode Edited ! Thanks for the suggestions.